# how to change contact form 7 Text Field Validation Error text Color red to white.

Tags: wordpress

[i want to change contact form 7 Text Field Validation Error text Color red to white. please solve my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3BfJ.jpg)

Comment: add this in style.css     .wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
 color: #fff !important;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below code in css

```
span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip{
 color : #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: sir i want to this for a single form. how i do.

Comment: take the id from the form id

Comment: Sir its My Contact form ID 

[contact-form-7 id="1255" title="Author Interest Form"]

Comment: check in the html form tag

Comment: sorry sir i can't find anything.

Comment: #wpcf7-f1255-p5-o1 span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip{
 color : #fff !important;
}

Comment: Sir, you have tried me many times for which thank you very much. But I would like to inform you that this code is not working. If you would suggest a solution then thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I've found. Now is working right. Thank you so so so much.